# Acumular valores en una variable al hacer click sobre un botón

Tags: reactjs

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en donde se muestra al usuario unos productos y se le da una cantidad de monedas para intercambiar por productos.

siempre que se intercambia un producto se actualiza la cantidad de monedas y se guardan en el local estorage.

en la variable let actualCoins traigo la cantidad de monedas del local storage 2000 digamos, El usuario puede recargar mas monedas haciendo click en los botones de abajo, (1000, 5000, 7500) dicha cifra se guarda en el estado rechargedCoins.

Necesito actualizar la variable actualCoins para que guarde la cantidad de monedas que tiene mas las que el usuario ha recargado al hacer click en los botones.

digamos vienen 2000 monedas en la variable actualCoins, el usuario hace click en button de 1000 y tendría 3000 monedas, posteriormente hace click en 5000, tendria 8000 monedas en total y así...

Como puedo hacer para que la variable actualCoins vaya guardando el acumulado?

yo hice actualCoins = actualCoins + rechargedCoins;

Pero siempre me suma 2000 al valor que trae el button en el estado rechargedCoins  y no sobre la suma acumulada. no acumula nada

Como podría hacer para que se guarde el acumulado en la variable.

Gracias por la ayuda.

```
function Recharge() {

    let actualCoins = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('actualCoins'));

    let [rechargedCoins, setRechargedCoins] = useState(0);

    let [updatedCoinsFigure, setUpdateCoinsFigure] = useState(0);

    const rechargeCoins = (e) => {
        setRechargedCoins(Number(e.target.value));
    }

    //siempre me suma 2000
    actualCoins = actualCoins + rechargedCoins;


    return (
        <RechargeSection className="container">
            <h1 className="mb-5">Recarga monedas aquí</h1>
            {
                rechargedCoins && <h2 className="mb-4">Has recargado {rechargedCoins} en total tienes {Number(actualCoins)+rechargedCoins} </h2>
            }

            <button onClick={rechargeCoins} className="d-block mb-3 pt-3 pb-3" value="1000">1000<FontAwesomeIcon className="ml-5"  icon={faCoins} /></button>
            <button onClick={rechargeCoins} className="d-block mb-3 pt-3 pb-3" value="5000">5000<FontAwesomeIcon className="ml-5"  icon={faCoins} /></button>
            <button onClick={rechargeCoins} className="d-block mb-3 pt-3 pb-3" value="7500">7500<FontAwesomeIcon className="ml-5"  icon={faCoins} /></button>
        </RechargeSection> 
    )
}

export default Recharge;
```

Answer (score 0):

Se puede persistir un valor `acumulador` entre **re- renders** con el hook `useRef`:

```
//inicializa con actualCoins
const acumuladorRecarga = useRef(actualCoins);
```

Sin embargo, `useRef` no dispara **re-renders** así que se configura un estado tipo `User Interface State: acumulador`, donde se va pasando el nuevo valor de la cantidad de recargas acumuladas entre re-renders:

```
let [acumulador, setAcumulador] = useState(actualCoins);
```

Finalmente, se hacen las operaciones correspondientes en la función `rechargeCoins`:

```
  const rechargeCoins = (e) => {
      //valor de la recarga
      const clickRecarga = Number(e.target.value);
      //sumo el valor de la recarga con la ref acumuladorRecarga
      //acumuladorRecarga mantiene la referencia entre re renders
      let a = clickRecarga + acumuladorRecarga.current;
      //re asigno el resultado de a, a la ref acumulador
      acumuladorRecarga.current = a;
      //seteo estados
      setRechargedCoins(clickRecarga);
      setAcumulador(acumuladorRecarga.current);
  }
```

Demo

```js
//localStorage.setItem('actualCoins',"2000");

function App() {
  //let actualCoins = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('actualCoins'));
  //emulando loclStorage para Stack Overflow code tool
  let actualCoins = 2000;
  let [rechargedCoins, setRechargedCoins] = React.useState(0);
  let [acumulador, setAcumulador] = React.useState(actualCoins);
  let [updatedCoinsFigure, setUpdateCoinsFigure] = React.useState(0);

  const acumuladorRecarga = React.useRef(actualCoins);

  const rechargeCoins = (e) => {
      //valor de la recarga
      const clickRecarga = Number(e.target.value);
      //sumo el valor de la recarga con la ref acumuladorRecarga
      //acumuladorRecarga mantiene la referencia entre re renders
      let a = clickRecarga + acumuladorRecarga.current;
      //re asigno el resultado de a a la ref acumulador
      acumuladorRecarga.current = a;
      //seteo estados
      setRechargedCoins(clickRecarga);
      setAcumulador(acumuladorRecarga.current);
  }
 
  return (
      <div>
          <h1 className="mb-5">Recarga monedas aquí</h1>
          {
              rechargedCoins && <h2 className="mb-4">Has recargado {rechargedCoins} en total tienes {acumulador} </h2>
          }

          <button onClick={rechargeCoins}  value="1000">1000</button>
          <button onClick={rechargeCoins}  value="5000">5000</button>
          <button onClick={rechargeCoins}  value="7500">7500</button>
      </div> 
  )
}


ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

---

#### Notas de campo

- No use `localStorage`en el demo debido a las restricciones del sitio y la herramienta de código, solo lo estoy emulando en una variable; pero no debe haber problema de tu lado al agregar las lineas de `localStorage`.

[hook useRef](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-useref-guide/)